# How to retrieve the specific data from HTML page using webzinc?

Tags: c#, .net, html-content-extraction

I am new to web zinc package,
My requirement is to retrieve the data form HTML Page.
Here i got some solution that to retrieve the whole page.
how to retrieve specific  content?
Used this code to retrieve  the whole page information.

```
    WebZinc MyWebZinc = new WebZinc();
    MyWebZinc.OpenPage("http://moneycentral.msn.com/" +
    "investor/external/excel/quotes.asp?SYMBOL=MSFT"); ---> this for open the HTML page.
```

To retrieve Paragraphs from a Page

Comment: here i need to edit the question and answer to this question right?

Comment: hi skippy is it right or i need to change more?